# MeteorJS - Can't use npm package as middleware with Picker Router

Tags: meteor, body-parser

I'm trying to use the example from MeteorChef's website

https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/server-side-routing-with-picker#!

this is my server server side code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
Picker.middleware( bodyParser.json() );

// Define our routes.
Picker.route('/tester', function (params, request, response, next) {
    // Now we have access to request.body!
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

but I receive the following error in console

```
W20180628-11:34:29.786(-5)? (STDERR) /home/insider/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_3.5jlc5e.4sxk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20180628-11:34:29.787(-5)? (STDERR)                                            throw(ex);
W20180628-11:34:29.787(-5)? (STDERR)                                            ^
W20180628-11:34:29.788(-5)? (STDERR)
W20180628-11:34:29.788(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: bodyParser.json is not a function
W20180628-11:34:29.788(-5)? (STDERR)     at uploader.js (imports/startup/server/uploader.js:3:31)
```

In Meteor **1.6.0.1** working fine, but after upgrade to **1.7.0.3** stop working, I just tried other npm packages but still get same error, thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you will get the best help, when you try to create a minimal app example that allows others to reproduce your problem with this specific packages and post this issue in Meteor's github issues.

Comment: I've hit the same issue. Seems to be to do with Picker blocking dynamic importing, https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9653#issuecomment-376514415